# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT with double ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, group-concat

I got a `GROUP_CONCAT` in which i need to `ORDER BY` 2 columns. Problem is that with the normal sintax i would use in any other `ORDER BY`, it will ignore the first column ordering only by the second one.

Example:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
    DC.reference_date,' - ',D.number,'/',D.year,' : ',
    IF(DC.notes IS NOT NULL,DC.notes,'')
    ORDER BY D.number, DC.reference_date SEPARATOR '\r\n'
)
```

with this i will get a list ordered by date (instead of by number and THEN by date):

```
2015-05-25 - 3714/2014 : id 17
2015-05-25 - 2729/2014 : id 19
2015-05-27 - 3714/2014 : id 21
2015-05-27 - 2729/2014 : id 20
2015-05-28 - 3714/2014 : id 18
```

and with this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
    DC.reference_date,' - ',D.number,'/',D.year,' : ',
    IF(DC.notes IS NOT NULL,DC.notes,'')
    ORDER BY D.number SEPARATOR '\r\n'
)
```

i obtain a list correctly order ONLY by number:

```
2015-05-27 - 3714/2014 : id 21
2015-05-28 - 3714/2014 : id 18
2015-05-25 - 3714/2014 : id 17
2015-05-27 - 2729/2014 : id 20
2015-05-25 - 2729/2014 : id 19
```

what i need is a list order this way:

```
2015-05-25 - 3714/2014 : id 17
2015-05-27 - 3714/2014 : id 21
2015-05-28 - 3714/2014 : id 18
2015-05-25 - 2729/2014 : id 19
2015-05-27 - 2729/2014 : id 20
```

any clue of why the `ORDER BY` is failing?

---

UPDATE as per strawberry request, here's a shortened version of the entire query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DC.reference_date,' - ',D.number,'/',D.year,' : ', IF(DC.notes IS NOT NULL,DC.notes,'') ORDER BY D.number SEPARATOR '\r\n') AS 'd_c', CD.contract_id
FROM gbdc AS DC
LEFT JOIN [...]
WHERE CD.cancel <> 1
AND BP.bill_id IS NULL
GROUP BY CD.contract_id
```

Comment: I see no difference in the ORDER BY clause..

Comment: @TravisG I was just comtemplating the same thing and I agree, they are identical.

Comment: @TravisG My fault, i copy and pasted the same fragment of code. Now, i've updated.

Comment: Erm, `order by number desc, date`

Comment: Are you sure the list is ordered correctly in the second example? The query reads `ORDER BY D.number` (no sorting direction, default is `ASC`) but the values of `D.number` are `3714`...`2729` (i.e. descending).

Comment: @Strawberry it's not an ASC/DESC problem. It is ordering only by date even with the DESC: `2015-05-25 - 3714/2014 : id 17
2015-05-25 - 2729/2014 : id 19
2015-05-27 - 3714/2014 : id 21
2015-05-27 - 2729/2014 : id 20
2015-05-28 - 3714/2014 : id 18`

Comment: Perhaps if we could see the actual query...

Comment: @axiac yes i'm sure. I just double checked running the query again to be sure i've posted the correct result.

Comment: @Strawberry i've updated the question with a shortened version of the query...

Comment: I cannot see the flaw in my answer. Perhaps we need proper DDLs too.

Comment: The query **does not** specify **DESC** in the `ORDER BY` clause but the results **are** ordered by `D.number` **DESC**. Maybe it's just a coincidence (?!) and, in fact, they are sorted by something else? (They are obviously not sorted by `reference_date` in the second result posted in the question).

Comment: @axiac in fact, in the second example there's no reference to an `ORDER BY reference_date`. But that's the code...and i can assure you that the result i've posted is the one i'm obtaining running the query

Comment: @axiac i've tried omitting the whole `ORDER BY` and this is the result: `2015-05-25 - 2729/2014 : id 19
2015-05-27 - 2729/2014 : id 20
2015-05-25 - 3714/2014 : id 17
2015-05-28 - 3714/2014 : id 18
2015-05-27 - 3714/2014 : id 21`. `ORDER BY D.number ASC` also fails because it orders the numbers in the `DESC` way. I really can't get the point...